# How to replace proxy list from \n to \r\n

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ubuntu-18.04, dos2unix

I want to replace proxy list on linux from **\n** to **\r\n**.

I got line breaks pasted with just **\n**.

So I need to replace **\n** *line breaks* to **\r\n**.

How can I be make this change?

Comment: `unix2dos` is your friend.

Comment: @Shawn - OP tagged the question with the `unix2dos` utility. I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: @jww he tagged it `dos2unix`. In the absence of more information, all I can assume is that he doesn't realize the opposite also exists.

Answer (score 0):

`unix2dos` is an utility which replaces Unix(\n) line breaks in a file with Windows(\r\n) line breaks.